# Running a method from another methods peramiters

Tags: java, function, methods, runnable, timed

I am trying to run a method inside a runnable from an API. I am not quite sure how to do this.

```
    public void startRepeatingTask(JavaPlugin plugin,final String taskName, 
                                         Long repeatTime, Callable<T> func){
    task = null;
    task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            if(!tasks.containsKey(taskName)){
            tasks.put(taskName, task.getTaskId());
            }
        }}, repeatTime);
   }
```

I want the method to be inside the run() function! Help please!

Comment: where tasks and task variables are defined??

Comment: @SachinVerma, I think `tasks` is defined outside of the function, and I believe it's a `Map` of some kind.  `task` is defined within the function.  However, it should have been defined with a specific type before, like `int task = 0;`.  I know from my experience with Bukkit that `runTaskLater` returns the task number, so that is what `task` means.